# .NET TranslateTransform + InvokePaint on button do not TranslateTransfrom button's text

Tags: c#, .net, controls, transparency, system.drawing

i'm trying to create a movable and resizable control, to achieve that i need transparency (to correctly handle drawing of resize handles). To achieve transparency i override OnPaintBackground of my control to paint each control under my resizable control.

I can correctly get each control under my resizable control painted exactly where they have to, but they miss their own text. Why? because TranslateTransform graphic method do not seem to apply on control's text but only on control's background and foreground (excluded text)

Here's the code I use:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground( PaintEventArgs pevent )
{
    ...
    pevent.Graphics.TranslateTransform( translateX, translateY );
    PaintEventArgs pe = new PaintEventArgs( pevent.Graphics, rect1 );
    InvokePaint( c, pe );
    ...
}
```

I also tried to avoid TranslateTransform method and use

```
    pevent.Graphics.RenderingOrigin
```

but I did not get any result.

How can i apply TranslateTransform on control's text?

Thank you.

Comment: You in general can't expect the control to not monkey with Graphics.Transform.  The right way to do this is by using the built-in support for transparency.  Set the ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor style and set the BackColor to Color.Transparent.  You'll get the transparency for free.

Comment: You are wrong! With ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor you don't have transparency, you just see the form through controls!

Comment: Seeing the form is of course transparency.  If you want to see something else then you have to change the control's Parent property.

Comment: I appreciate your help but that's not a solution: to simulate REAL transparency you MUST draw controls behind you and then paint yourself. You can read about this anywhere on the web. However that's not the point of my question. My question is about TranslateTransform. If you try using TranslateTransform on a Control it will move anything but the text of the control. Any idea on why that happens? How to move text too?

Comment: I addressed that in the comment.  Yes, this won't work if you are overlapping multiple controls.  An alternative is use an owned transparent window that overlays the controls.  Or the code in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943454)

Comment: Hi dear friend! I checked out the code you pointed me out. Surprisingly it suffers  the same issue i'm writing about: Control's text is not drawn in the right place. That Code does what i do in a quite similar way. how can i post you a pic?